# MySQL Single Left Join Very Slow

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

```
SELECT
    contacts.email, emails_stats.id FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN
    emails_stats ON contacts.id = emails_stats.contact_id
WHERE
    contacts.client_code = 121212121212
GROUP BY
    contacts.email;
```

*This query taken 10.2s*

Table `contacts`:

Rows: ~74k; Indexes: *primary* and *client_code*

Table `emails_stats`

Rows: ~20k; Indexes: *primary* and *contact_id*

The query *explain*:

```
1   SIMPLE  contacts    ref client_code client_code 9   const   2104    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  emails_stats    index   NULL    contact_id  36  NULL    19394   Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE contacts:

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE emails_stats:

```
CREATE TABLE `emails_stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email_event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contact_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email_event_id` (`email_event_id`),
  KEY `contact_id` (`contact_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19194 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Expected Result:

```
email                       id
aaaaaaaaa99@yahoo.com.br    136
bbbbbbbbb99@yahoo.com.br    365
ccccccccc99@yahoo.com.br    765
```

Comment: You aren't including emails_stats in any critiera so why are you joining by  them? What happens  with explain if you don't `FORCE INDEX` (it looks like client_code is a better index)? Why are you using `DISTINCT`, a) its grouped by that, b) its contracts.id the PK? Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE contacts` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE emails_stats`. What example results are you after?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the comment. I updated the question adding the `SHOW CREATE TABLE contacts|emails_stats`. I'm using `DISTINCT` to get different values from `contacts.email` column. Yes, the `contacts.id` is the primary key.

Comment: What contracts.email? It isn't in the query. You have presented a broken query with no description of what example results you are after. It can't be answered in the current form. When you `GROUP BY contacts.id` the output will be a unique contract.id so `DISTINCT` is not needed and created ambiguities as to what you want. Show example results (asking for second time).

Comment: In its current form the ideal simplification yielding identical results and performance improvement of this question is `SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE client_code = 121212121212` and creating an index on client code `CREATE INDEX client_code ON contacts(client_code)`.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I added expected result and changed de `EXPLAIN`. Look to the query, i added `contacts.email` and `emails_stats.id` select

Comment: Thanks for changing the question. Is email unique per contact.id? I assume you still want email to be unique in the output? If so which/all happens for when there is more than one emails_stats.id per email? Do you want the max/min/latest/all (as comma separated list).

Comment: @danblack Yes, I want the email to be unique. If there is more than one emails_stats.id per email, I populate the table `emails_stats` with the `contact_id` and `email_event_id` . The email is not unique per `contact.id`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are grouping by `contracts.email`, there needs to be an aggregate expression over emails_stats.id, which I've chosen as `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    contacts.email, GROUP_CONCAT(emails_stats.id) FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN
    emails_stats ON contacts.id = emails_stats.contact_id
WHERE
    contacts.client_code = 121212121212
GROUP BY
    contacts.email;
```

As this lookup is by `client_code`, to enable this to perform, creating an index on `client_code` needs to be at the first part of the index. As `contacts.email` is used by the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` results, putting email at the end of the index will save a secondary lookup of the email, and being in the index, its already sorted and hence grouped together.

```
CREATE INDEX client_code_email ON contacts(client_code,email)
```

This will enable the `WHERE` clause to be fast. In Innodb which is used, the contacts.id is the PK at the end of the key, this is use the JOIN which is ideal.

The JOIN to `email_stats` is on `contract_id` which already has an index. `email_stats.id` is the PK already at the end of this index which gets used in the result set.

Comment: nice suggestion! you are absolutely right - in the original form of query 2nd table don't change anything! :-)

Comment: I added the `emails_stats` to appear in the `SELECT` result set. Look the new modifications in the question, i added the expected result. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @ypercubeᵀ The second table is needed because I want a specific column from there

Comment: Totally written answer based on totally different question. Please aim for complete and correct questions showing edge cases next time @Kafer76

Answer (score 1):

**UPD** - there is no reason to edit the answer, after changing the question, logic is changed for 100% as well and no reasons to repeat the @danblack's answer.

The only one is possible to add - the more correct and full the question, the more fast and correct answers!

---

1. as mentioned in comments - you do not need to include **DISTINCT** in the query code,
   you already have **GROUP BY**
2. you also do not need **FORCE INDEX**
3. but you **have not index** for **client_code**, and this is the most important part - this is only one that could reduce the number of scanned rows, without this index mysql always will make the full table scan and only then sort filtered rows

suggestions:

- exclude from code DISTINCT and FORCE INDEX
- add index on table contacts for client_code or possible (client_code, id)

Comment: Good summary. Note that MySQL PK is always implicitly at the end of secondary keys so `client_code` is sufficient.

Comment: I would, on the contrary, recommend removing GROUP BY and leaving DISTINCT. On the modelling dataset (1kk records, 32k distinct values) the execution time is ~7% less.

Comment: @danblack "..PK is always implicitly at the end of secondary keys.." For InnoDB engine only.

Comment: @Akina - as a variant. I personally prefer GROUP BY - just because in most of the case some other columns there - max, avg and etc

Comment: In the `contacts` table, `client_code` and `id` column are indexes. Look the new modifications in the question above. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You say `client_code` is indexed, but the `CREATE TABLE` does not show it!

Answer (score 0):

UUIDs are terrible for performance when the table becomes bigger than can be cached in RAM.  Did this happen?

How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Add this covering, composite index:

```
INDEX(client_code, email, id) -- in this order
```